# Error importing MBOX file

Tags: import, regular-expressions

I am trying to import the mbox file generated by gmail. Using the [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) command.

```
k = Import["All mail Including Spam and Trash.mbox", "MBOX"]
```

> > RegularExpression::int32: Operation in RegularExpression not supported for machine integer parameters greater than 2147483647. >>
> >
> > During evaluation of In[1]:= RegularExpression::int32: Operation in RegularExpression not supported for machine integer parameters greater than 2147483647. >>
> >
> > During evaluation of In[1]:= RegularExpression::int32: Operation in RegularExpression not supported for machine integer parameters greater than 2147483647. >>
> >
> > During evaluation of In[1]:= General::stop: Further output of RegularExpression::int32 will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
> >
> > During evaluation of In[1]:= Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as MBOX format. >>
>
> ```
> $Failed
> ```

What is the problem here and how can I solve it? I am using *Mathematica 8.0*.

Thanks,.

Comment: What is the file size? Have you tried to import a small one?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic rules of the site. It would be helpful to know if you experience that problem with other files as well, most importantly if you have an example of non-private data that reproduces the problem. help us to help you. Please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) accordingly.

Comment: I suspect you need to look at external ulilities to see if they can parse it.

Comment: The file size is about 5GB. The system has 512GB RAM so I thought RAM should not be an issue. I have parsed it with Python's mailbox module and it works fine with it.

Comment: ram is not the only factor that limits sizes of things.  use python to create some smaller files and see if you can import those. In the end `Import` is a black box and when it doesn't work there isn't much to do about it, but it would be useful to identify exactly what the limitation is. 2147483647 is the max for signed short integer just by the way.